# 1 month baby crying since last night

Tags: infant, crying

Our baby turned one month and some days old. He had been giving us a hard time all night. Crying and being unsettling, crying. He likes someone rocking his bouncy all the time. But we can't shake his bed 
We tried everything such as turning him over, massage, tummy and back rub. My back hurts after holding him on my shoulder for a long time as I cannot stand and he won't let me sit down. 
What else can we do? He sleeps in next2me crib, The closet we can get is rocking his bouncy but that too isn’t enough.
What should we do?

Comment: I'm confused: a month or so ago you asked about your 2.5 month old.  This is a different child?

Comment: Has he been inconsolable, or just unsettled/fussy?

Comment: @Joe yes he is my second one

Comment: You have both a 3 month old and a 1 month old?

Comment: @GendoIkari where do u think is 3 months old baby mentioned?

Comment: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/39719/hungry-infant-always-ready-to-suckle-and-crying

Comment: @GendoIkari sorry, I meant to say 2.5 weeks. I will update. I guess parenting got me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is only while sleeping or all day?

I can share with you my experience: my boy used to cry almost non-stop for 4~6 hours, then sleep for 1~2 hours (and you could see he was suffering). I complained for everybody, but everybody said: "baby crying is normal". But i knew it was not normal.

So we went to the doctor and he saw it was not normal too. So, with the help of 2 doctors we found he was allergic to milk's protein (milk allergy).

My wife had to stop eating everything that contained milk. It took around 15~40 days to make effect on her milk to the baby.

He got A LOT BETTER. But still has something wrong with him (she stoped eating eggs and soy now to try find the other factor).

We found "early"  (2 months old). Some ppl takes YEARS to find out.

Common sympthons:
* blood in feces;
* irritability;
* difficulties sleeping;
* polka dots on the skin (used google translator);

Ofc, i'm not saying your child has it. You should see a doctor. But like i said: if it happens the whole day, maybe you can have something similar to my problem. If it's only at night, maybe it's totally different. I bought a mamaroo to 'rocky' him. Works SOMETIMES hahaha.

### Good luck!

edit: my son had no blood on the feces (making it harder to find out)

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible reasons for a baby of that age to cry, some medical, and some 'normal'.

Possibilities include food allergy, [colic](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/39471/why-colics-in-newborns-have-a-tendency-to-occur-at-the-end-of-the-day) (unexplained prolonged nighttime crying that is likely developmental rather than pathological), illness/pain, trapped wind, over stimulation, reflux, or a growth spurt.

If your baby is truly inconsolable (continues to cry hard even when carried, walked, taken outside, fed, whatever normally soothes him), seems unusually distressed, or shows other symptoms of illness (fever, rash, stomach illness, lethargy, etc), you should first consult a doctor.  If what you have is an unhappy baby that can be calmed but cries again soon after, with more of a 'unhappy mood' vs 'obvious distress', you can try investigate simpler causes and solutions.

If your baby is happy as long as he is held upright, it could be a sign of reflux, even in absence of excessive spitting up.  Babies with mild reflux often find the sitting position of a swing or bouncer comforting, but should not be left to sleep there, as it's not safe.  They may also feel better if held upright for a while after feeding. If you suspect reflux, food allergy, or other stomach discomforts, please get the advice of a doctor as well.

Some babies crave constant movement, and this can be exhausting for parents.  There are clip on vibrating units made for this purpose that you can add to the baby's bed or bouncy seat to give your arms a rest.  A rocking chair for you or electric swing for baby can also offer some relief from the night time pacing.  Some babies also love to be bounced in the arms of a parent sitting on a yoga ball, or pushed in the stroller in the evening to sleep.

Other soothing options are to take the baby outside for fresh air, to give a deep, warm bath, or to swaddle the baby snuggly.  Some babies respond well to soft music or white noise as well.  These are all essentially in the same family of providing pleasant sensory input that can help to improve a 'bad baby mood' or soothe an overstimulated baby's nerves.

For wind, you can do some gentle stretches like 'bicycle legs' and bringing baby's knees to tummy to help pass gas.  Don't use too much force, and try to work 'with' your baby's movements.

For a growth spurt, feed on demand, even if it seems too soon.  If you are bottle feeding consider using ['paced' bottle feeding](https://www.mamanatural.com/paced-bottle-feeding/) so that the baby is able to eat more slowly.  Fussing a lot at night during a growth spurt, and poor sleep along with it, is a fact of life for many babies, and will pass.

A popular general set of techniques for unsettled infants is call 'the 5 S'.  [5 S Method](https://wehavekids.com/parenting/The-5-S-Method-to-Soothe-Newborns).  This involves swaddling, shushing, swinging (or swaying), sucking, and side or stomach position to comfort a crying baby.  You can use all 5 together, or start with one and add more as needed.  I found this was reasonably effective for my own baby, although it isn't really any less tiring than holding on your shoulder for long periods.  I sometimes used a recording of myself, or from youtube, for the shushing sounds, as I got tired or sore throat from so much shhh'ing during colic episodes!

Answer (score 0):

Call a doctor.  If they are crying more than 3 hours straight or not eating every 3 hours, you need to get a doctor involved.